# Excluding jar file duplicate from build

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, duplicates, redundancy

First of all, I got this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nostra13/universalimageloader/cache/disc/DiskCache.class
```

I use the UniversalImageLoader jar in my app project, but also I have a library module which also uses the exact same jar.

I tried to add something like that to my app build.gradle file:

```
 compile (project(':imagesubsampling')){
        exclude group: 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader', module: 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader'
    }
```

or

```
 compile (project(':imagesubsampling')){
        exclude group: 'com.nostra13', module: 'universalimageloader'
    }
```

or

```
 compile (project(':imagesubsampling')){
        exclude group: 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader'
    }
```

Nothing works.
Therefore, my question is:

```
 compile (project(':imagesubsampling')){
       <What to write here to exclude jar file from this library>
    }
```

Is there a better solution to get rid of duplicates?
What to write exactly?

Comment: just add compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5' and remove jar from lib

Comment: also check https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup

Comment: What are the correct group and module values for `project(':imagesubsampling')`? Can you show imagesubsampling's build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue when there're **more than one** universal
image loader reference in your project(maybe in the libs folder, or in dependencies of the project,sublibs).

Check again all build.gradle files(in android studio) in your project.**Keep one and delete all others would solve the problem**.